# Fallback image URL if no featured image exists via a shortcode function

Tags: php, functions, post-thumbnails

What I'm trying to do is add a fallback image to this shortcode function that grabs the featured image to account for the possibility that a post has no featured image. (This function creates a shortcode because I need to use that within another plugin that requires the shortcode to generate HTML display.)

I've read the related questions and none deal with a shortcode or the fact that I need to `return` only the image URL.

*This works and returns the URL of the featured image:*

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_featured_image_shortcode');

function register_featured_image_shortcode(){
add_shortcode('my_get_thumbsrc', 'my_get_thumbsrc');
}

function my_get_thumbsrc($id) {
global $post;
$id = ($id) ? $id : $post->ID;

if ( has_post_thumbnail($id)) {

$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($id), 'inthenews-thumbnail');

return $image_url[0]; // return just the url

}
}
```

*This doesn't work; I get an empty `<img src` field in page source:*

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_featured_image_shortcode');

function register_featured_image_shortcode(){
add_shortcode('my_get_thumbsrc', 'my_get_thumbsrc');
}

function my_get_thumbsrc($id) {
global $post;
$id = ($id) ? $id : $post->ID;

if ( has_post_thumbnail($id)) {

$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($id), 'inthenews-thumbnail');

return $image_url[0]; // return just the url
}
else  {
    return get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .' /white-placeholder-200x100.png';
}
}
```

**So how to I add the fallback image `white-placeholder-200x100.png` with an `else` construct? Is `return` the wrong way to provide the URL? `echo` doesn't work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a typo in the provided code: an extra space between the apostrophe and the forward slash before "white-placeholder."

Second, without examining the underlying logic in detail, I might try for the else statement:

```
else {

$placeholder_image = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/white-placeholder-200x100.png';

return $placeholder_image;

}
```

Comment: Ha, I'm sure I tried returning a variable, i.e. , $placeholder_image, but I guess not. Works fine, thanks.

Comment: My pleasure - and thanks for marking my answer satisfactory, and boosting me over the magic 50 rep mark! I have only 6,160 or so points to catch up to you, as of this writing, so consider me hot on your heels.